Azure Vision Studio, Azure Content Safety studio permission error on Azure Student subscription
I am learning Azure Vision studio and Azure Content Safety studio. I signed in by Microsoft Azure Account with Azure Student subscription. but I am getting following error

It seems my subscription needs permission/ roles, but I cannot figure out exactly.
Is Azure student subscription is not allowed for Microsoft Azure AI Studio?
Do I need to raise request for special permission?

If you are using a student subscription, you may need to check if it has the necessary permissions and roles.

Get started using Vision Studio
Document Intelligence Studio FAQ
Azure OpenAI Service FAQ


@Arko I assigned Cognitive Service Contributor, Cognitive Service User, Cognitive Service Custom Vision Contributor Roles to current subscription. Do I need to add some specific role.

I think Cognitive Services Contributor
Cognitive Services User
Cognitive Services Custom Vision Contributor should be enough, , try adding the Reader role once. Once done check if your account has the necessary roles- az role assignment list --assignee 
If none of the above steps resolve the issue, contact Azure support for further assistance. Sometimes some azure services are not available for a particular region cz ideally with all these permission it should work
